# timer runs twice in my service

Tags: android, service, timer

i am using service in my application. its a launcher application. i used timer in  my service which have a pooling frequency of 1 minute. my application is working fine in normal scenario. but  when i restart my phone the timer from my runs twice in a minute for example:

**11:00:15,  11:00:23,  11:01:15, 11:01:23, 11:02:15, 11:02:23.......**

please help me guys here is my service code:

```
if (mTimer != null) {
            mTimer.cancel();
            mTimer = new Timer();
           // mTimer.schedule(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), file_saving_time, file_saving_time);
           mTimer.schedule(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), file_saving_time, file_saving_time);

        } else {
            // recreate new
            mTimer = new Timer();
            mTimer.schedule(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), file_saving_time, file_saving_time);
        }
```

i start my service from onCreate() of activity class and destroy it from onDestroy() method.

Comment: Is there any chance that this if-statement is run twice?

Comment: Have you tried  mTimer.purge(); ?

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable   no

Answer (score 0):

Try this always cancel the `Timer` before making new instance.

Here `TimeDisplayTimerTask()` object is being created everytime so cancel it before

```
public class MyTimer extends TimerTask
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {

                }
    }

if (mTimer != null) {
       try{
      mTimer.cancel();
}
catch(Exception ee){}
try{
     mytimer.cancel();
}catch(Exception ee){}


            mTimer = new Timer();
            mytimer=new MyTimer();
            mTimer.schedule(mytimer, file_saving_time, file_saving_time);


        } else {
            // recreate new
mytimer=new MyTimer();
            mTimer = new Timer();
            mTimer.schedule(mytimer, file_saving_time, file_saving_time);
        }
```

Comment: i already cancel the timer if already exist in my code check if else conditon.

Comment: @ShivanshuVerma Here TimeDisplayTimerTask() object is being created everytime so cancel it before you is not cancel timertask but you is cancelling only timer please read my answer again properly